# Persistent zombie process in android make network sockets busy

Tags: android, shell, sockets, adb, zombie-process

in my device i have a program that works good but some times it crashes and when i run next time it will give me error and crashes again and more and more..

After looking for problem i found that the program after crashing goes to 'Zombie' status and will not release the 'Network Server Socket' resources and after next execution program will run but errors that "Server sockets is already in use!"
and crashing!

Note: my program's package name is AndroidEX.AndroidEX but zombies process name is 'oidEX.AndroidEX'

i tried to kill the zombie process but i found we cannot kill zombie process because it is already died, i killed it's PPID (zygote) and the Android System will go to soft restart but after booting..i see zombie is here yet and not cleared but zombies PPID changed to 1 (init process!)
anyone knows what should i do for clearing zombie process and release network sockets?

i tried these for killing and clearing the zombie in ADB:

adb shell kill ZOMBIES_PID

adb shell kill ZOMBIES_PPID

adb shell busybox killall zygote

adb shell busybox killall system_server

adb shell busybox killall init

adb shell am force-stop AndroidEX.AndroidEX

adb shell am force-stop oidEX.AndroidEX

adb shell busybox killall AndroidEX.AnadroidEX

But zombie process didn't go!
(Android version is 4.1)

[image]

Network Sockets in netstat:
[image]